# Lost MSCRM Developer Tools Blog / Collection

Tags: c#-4.0, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

About a year ago I was working a CRM2011 customization project and found a website / blog that had 50+ development tools for CRM 2011. Sitemap editor was there, Ribbon Editor, VS plugins specifically for CRM tons of java & jquery tools like intellisense.

Some like the sitemap editor I remember the name but others not so much. I know this isn't specifically a programming question but I was hoping someone might know the blog or at least people can chime in with their tool(s) to help me build my toolbox back.

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're referring to the following site:

http://everythingcrm.net/2012/01/24/over-40-useful-dynamics-crm-2011-tools-utilities-scripts-controls/

You could also search in codeplex, there are tons of CRM tools available.

Answer (score 1):

The [CRM ToolBox](https://xrmtoolbox.codeplex.com/) is a good start